# Set bodybg after button clicking in wp loop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is my wp loop:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
<div style="background:url(<?php echo $url; ?>);">
    <button id="change">preview</button>
</div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

After clicking on button "change" it should change my body background to $url for e.g.

```
<body style="background:url($url);
```

where $url is thumbnail url

Any ideas how to make it?
Greetings

Comment: Wordpress incudes jQuery, so `jQuery('#change').click(function(){...});` is a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I noticed you are using id="change". Id is unique and if your loop makes more than one button with the same Id, it won't work. make class="change". I've edited the rest for you.

here is a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/2bt8Q/1/

You should essentially load your url's as the value of a hidden input, like so:

```
<body>
<div>
    <button class="change">preview<input type="hidden" value="http://pngimg.com/upload/tree_PNG2517.png"/></button>
</div>
</body>
```

Then using jQuery:

```
$('.change').on('click', function(){
    $(document.body).css('background', 'url('+$(this).find('input').val()+')');
});
```

When the button is clicked, it will change your document.body's background to whatever the URL is.

Thus your php file should look like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
<div>
    <button class="change">preview<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $url; ?>"/></button>
</div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.